# When using Tornado with WTForms {{ form.field }} display "<input name='field'>" in place of input field?

Tags: python, tornado, wtforms

I am using Tornado on Python 2.7 along with wtforms_tornado and wtforms.
I have already developed an Project in Flask using WTForms.
I started to change that project from Flask to Tornado but got stuck at this point.

run.py

```
class SignupForm(Form):
    email=StringField('email',[
    validators.Required(message='Email Required'),
    ],)

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        form=SignupForm()
        self.render('templates/home.html',form=form)

class SignupHandler(RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        form=SignupForm(self.request.arguments)
        if form.validate():
            email=form.data['email']
            self.write(email)
        else:
            loader=template.Loader('templates/')
            self.write(loader.load('home.html').generate(form=form))
```

home.html

```
<form  enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/signup' method='POST'>
    {{ form.email }}
<input type='submit' value='Sign Up' />
</form>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1r9P.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable [Tornado's auto-escape feature](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html) for that part of your template:

```
{% raw form.email %}
```

Comment: Thanks because based on your answer I found how to do it and it worked for me. Just added {% autoescape None %} at the top of the html file.